# Select from list with list as property

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to select from a list where the list contains a sub list.
I have two classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Services> Services { get; set; }
}

public class Services
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}
```

Then I have a method:

```
       public static List<Person> GetPeople()
        {
           List <Services> serviceList1 = new List<Services>();
           List <Services> serviceList2 = new List<Services>();
           var service = new Services
               {
                   Id = 1,
                   Name = "Service 1"
               };

           serviceList1.Add(service);

           service = new Services
               {
                   Id = 2,
                   Name = "Service 2"
               };
           serviceList1.Add(service);

           service = new Services
               {
                   Id = 3,
                   Name = "Service 3"
               };
           serviceList2.Add(service);

           service = new Services
               {
                   Id = 4,
                   Name = "Service 4"
               };
           serviceList2.Add(service);

           List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
           var person = new Person
               {
                   FirstName = "Bill",
                   LastName = "Murray",
                   Services = serviceList1
               };
           people.Add(person);

           person = new Person
           {
               FirstName = "Chevy",
               LastName = "Chase",
               Services = serviceList2
           };
           people.Add(person);

           return people //Where Service Id = 3
        }
```

I want to return the person list where each item includes Service 3 as a service.
Should I be using SelectMany or a where clause. I just can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you spell it out you should be pretty much there:
Find all people who have a service with id 3

```
return people.Where(p => p.Services.Any(s => s.Id == 3)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
return people.Where(p => p.Services.Any(service => service.Id == 3)).ToList();
```